# Displaying images with Hevea (Latex)

Tags: graphics, latex2html, hevea

What is the correct way to include images so that [Hevea](http://hevea.inria.fr/) will produce correct html output? I tried the following:

Latex code (test.tex):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hevea}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
An image.
\includegraphics{python.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Compilation

```
$ hevea test.tex
```

In the html produced, the image is broken (0 bytes).

Does Hevea not support jpg images? Do they need to be converted to say, eps? I looked at the Hevea documentation, but I found it hard to understand, especially on how imagen should be used.

When I try the same with pdflatex, I am able to get a PDF that shows the image.

I am using this on OS X 10.8.1 with the latest Hevea/MacTeX packages.

Comment: JPG should be supported by an *2HTML converter because its a standard WWW format. EPS support however would surprise me. Note that such tools are only border-line on-topic here.

Comment: OK. Could you suggest a better place to post questions on such tools? I am also struggling with htlatex. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[HeVeA's guide](http://hevea.inria.fr/doc/manual036.html#sec162) discusses this problem. You should use `\imgsrc` to include bitmaps, like so:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hevea}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
An image.
\imgsrc{python.jpg}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you should be able to include the normal `graphics` package.